# Remove data attribute on click function using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is the stripped snippet of code I'm having difficulties with to start explaining my question.

**Button that triggers function:**

```
 <button id="deleteItem" type="button">Delete</button>
```

**Input field attribute I'm trying to update**

```
<input id="quantity" type="text" name="field" min="1" value="1" data-price="10">
```

**jQuery to process**

```
$(function() {
    // Bind an action to the deleteItem - click event
    $("#deleteItem").on('click', function() {

        var deleteQuantity = document.getElementById("quantity");

        // Add 0 value to the data-price value
        deleteQuantity.data('price','0');

    });
});
```

---

When click event is triggered I get this from console.

*Uncaught TypeError: deleteQuantity.data is not a function*

Comment: `var deleteQuantity = $("#quantity");`

Comment: or simple $('#quantity')....

Comment: You're trying to use a jQuery method (`.data()`) on a plain vanilla JavaScript object `deleteQuantity`

Comment: You would need something like `deleteQuantity.setAttribute('data-price', 0)` if you want to use vanilla JS

Comment: @RamisWachtler, yes, but why in this case, why to mix jQuery and native js syntax, if jQuery is already used?

Comment: @sinisake It wasn't actually meant as a comment the OP should follow, just wanted to point it out, so OP also knows the vanilla JS way of doing it. :) I'm totally with you, that it makes not much sense using vanilla JS for this if you already included jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select input like this `$('input#quantity')` and change `data-price` with `attr()`

```js
$('#deleteItem').click(function() {
  $('#quantity').attr('data-price', 0)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="deleteItem" type="button">Delete</button>
 <input id="quantity" type="text" name="field" min="1" value="1" data-price="10">
```

Comment: It is better to not qualify an ID selector; it actually slows down the selection process. A selector with `#quantity` will use `document.getElementById('quantity')`, which gets the element immediately. A selector with `input#quantity` either has to get the element, then check if it's an `input`, or find all `input`s, then check the id on each one...

Comment: Yea you are right, also `id`'s must be unique so there is no point.

Comment: Well @NenadVracar I've already tried that before but I wasn't getting it. Now I've reproduced it with your answer and still not updating it. There must be something else going on as buttons and inputs are outputted by loop assigned by index number like this `deleteItem-0` and `quantity-0`. I've checked it many times and each delete button updates input field attribute respectively. Because there are other input fields with `id` selector like `price-0` and `deleteItem-0` button does the job well.